# get instagram followers list with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code that i have written gives me 1000 followers per 10 minute which is a slow process for getting 18 million follower list. I would like to have access to prada's follower list in shorter amount of time.thanks for your replies the slow process is instagram limitations fault. So give a way to get the follower list faster.

```
 # Get instance
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
L.login(username, password)        # (login)


# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, "prada")

# Print list of followees



follow_list = []
count=0
for followee in profile.get_followers():
    follow_list.append(followee.username)
    file = open("prada_followers.txt","a+")
    file.write(follow_list[count])
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    print(follow_list[count])
    count=count+1
# (likewise with profile.get_followers())
```

Comment: I/O operations are slow. If you need speed, shorten it down as much as possible. Also, you're opening and closing the file for each iteration, which is incredibly inefficient.

Comment: thanks for your reply but my problem is instagram limitations itself. Every time i get error 429 for too many queries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Main bottleneck may be pulling the data from instagram, but you can improve speed by opening and closing only once outside of the loop; also you don't really need the array:

```
file = open("prada_followers.txt","a+")
for followee in profile.get_followers():
    username = followee.username
    file.write(username + "\n")
    print(username)

file.close()
```