# Get Instagram followers list with python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

I'm beginner in python programming and i want to export my Instagram followers and following list into an excel file. Searching on Google i found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264169/get-instagram-followers-list-with-python). I will paste the code bellow:

```
# Get instance
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
L.login(username, password)        # (login)


# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, "prada")

# Print list of followees
follow_list = []
count=0
for followee in profile.get_followers():
    follow_list.append(followee.username)
    file = open("prada_followers.txt","a+")
    file.write(follow_list[count])
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    print(follow_list[count])
    count=count+1
# (likewise with profile.get_followers())
```

All i edited was the username and the password from "Login or load session" section and "prada" from "Obtain profile metadata" section. So my code is looking like this:

```
# Login or load session
L.login("myusername", "mypassword")        # (login)


# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, "myusername")
```

Although I reset the password I still get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/ ..... /insta_followers.py", line 6, in <module>
    L.login("myusername", "mypassword")        # (login)
  File "C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\instaloader\instaloader.py", line 483, in login
    self.context.login(user, passwd)
  File "C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\instaloader\instaloadercontext.py", line 254, in login
    raise BadCredentialsException('Login error: Wrong password.')
instaloader.exceptions.BadCredentialsException: Login error: Wrong password.
```

I'm 100% the password is working because i tested in browser. My password contains uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers and signs. It is possible to get this error because one of the characters from the password? Or maybe because i recently reset the password? Can you give me some advice please?

I'm using PyCharm Community 2020.2 and Python 3.8.

Thank you

L.E.

My final code is looking like this:

```
# Get instance
import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
username = "myusername"
password = "mypassword"
L.login(username, password)  # (login)

# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, username)

# Print list of followees
follow_list = []
count = 0
for followee in profile.get_followers():
    follow_list.append(followee.username)
    file = open("prada_followers.txt", "a+")
    file.write(follow_list[count])
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    print(follow_list[count])
    count = count + 1
# (likewise with profile.get_followers())
```

Comment: To be sure the the password doesn't have accidental escape characters, put `r` in front of the password (e.g. `r'password'`)

Comment: I tried like you told me but still not working.

# Login or load session
username = 'myusername'
password = r'mypassword'
L.login(username, password)  # (login)

Comment: After 24+ hours still not working, i get the same error, is very frustrating. What should i do?

Comment: If you update your post with the exact code you are running (credentials omitted, of course) I will run it and see what I get. What environment are you running this in? Do you have 2FA enabled?

Comment: I edited my initial post and at the end of post you will find my final code. I'm using PyCharm Community 2020.2. No 2FA enabled, i login only with username and password, no text message or authentification app. Thank you for your help

Comment: Just tested it with my account, and it didn't seem to work with a sub-account (so one linked to another), but it worked fine for my primary account. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: No, it is the only instagram account that i have, i don't use multiple accounts.

Comment: I might recommend following the `instaloader` FAQ/help section; it might be useful. But as it stands, your code (login part at least) is *not* the problem, so it's something Instagram/your account related. Sorry

Comment: Ok :( Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code exactly with my own Instagram account and it works. Check your password is being input as a raw string and see if that has any effect.

```
password = r'********'
```

Divulging some details of your new password slightly lol, it could be that you have a backslash or two in there, which need to be ignored!

Comment: I tried with r" but still not working, same error.

# Login or load session
username = 'myusername'
password = r'mypassword'
L.login(username, password)  # (login)

I don't know to much about programming but i'm thinking maybe because i reseted my password today and has not been updated in all instagram databases. Maybe what I'm saying is stupid, but is that a possibility?

Comment: Doesn't sound too stupid to me. Can't find any info on it tho.

Comment: After 24+ hours still not working, i get the same error, is very frustrating. What should i do?

Comment: as someone else mentioned, do you have 2fa enabled on your account? I didn't know that was a thing on instagram, but if it is, and if you have it enabled, it would probably mess things up.

Comment: You need to disable two-factor authentication. If you are using this as a module to include in a project, add a disclaimer that mentions this. I tested on two accounts: one with 2fa and one without. The one without works without any problems, but too many sign-ins will block your account. With 2fa, you will never be suspended, but some hacky code can allow you in.

Comment: all I see is stars